# Magento 2 - overselling products on the web-site

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product

We're having the issue with many of our clients. They have a lot of products and customers buy a lot of products through different promotions. So sometimes we have an issue when one size/color is already out of stock (inventory 0, no backorders, status: out of stock) but the item is still available for sale on the storefront. It leads to overselling which is absolutely not good. After some time (I believe that's cache/indexer) quantity and stock status adjust itself and issue disappears. Does anybody have any thoughts on how to keep stock status up-to-date ALWAYS?

Answer (score 1):

You can set indexer reindex in a particular time like below:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/your/site/root/bin/magento index:reindex <index_type>
```

If you want to see  then please use below command:

```
magento_root/php bin/magento indexer:info
```

In your case you have to add "cataloginventory_stock" in index type.

Hope it will helps you !!!

Comment: We will have a problem of doing that cause reindexing catalog with ~10000 products after each minute will tear the site down.